# Node.js convert excel to JSON

Tags: node.js, excel

```js
var question = [{
    "keys": 1,
    "titles": "Malawi is a country in which continent?",
    "method":"single",
    "answer":"Africa",
    "options":[{
        option1:"Africa",
        option2:"Asia",
        option3:"Europe",
        option4:"Australia"
    }]
}];
```

So questions would be an array of `JSON` structure of questions.

The image is a sample of the actual excel file and I have to make it look like the above `JSON` above.
[excel sample for view](http://uc.seekdon.com/excel-png.png)

Comment: The image link isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SheetJS's [js-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) or [xlsjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsjs) (doesn't support xlsx).

They're pretty easy to use and support multi-sheet workbooks as well.

**Update**

For comma or tab delimited data, you could try the parser from [this](https://github.com/shancarter/Mr-Data-Converter) repo.

Comment: that does not support excel csv file

Comment: Would be nice if you mention that in your question. I'm adding another link to my answer.